# node -v showing old version of node

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm on MacOS, and I want my system to use the latest version of nodejs. I've installed the latest version of nodejs from the nodejs website.

`node -v` gives me: v14.15.0

Running `where node` in terminal gives me these 2 paths:

/Users/GenTan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/node

/usr/local/bin/node

I want to remove the v14.15.0, and only have the latest version of node on my system. What's the safest way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you no longer wish to use NVM, you can [uninstall it](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#uninstalling--removal). That way, the only version of Node left in your PATH is the system version.

You could also keep NVM. If you do `nvm ls` you'll see what versions you've got installed. One of them has a little arrow next to it, which is the current version. For example:

```
        v15.8.0
->      v16.0.0
        v18.4.0
         system
default -> 16.0 (-> v16.0.0)
```

Note there's also one called `system`. If you switch to that one with `nvm use system`, you'll use the one you installed yourself.

You can then use `nvm alias default system` to mark that as the default. When you then run `nvm ls`, you get:

```
        v15.8.0
        v16.0.0
        v18.4.0
->       system
default -> system
```